# Migrating Django-CMS 2.4.3 to Django-CMS 3.1.1

Tags: django-cms

I have several django-cms 2.4.3 (django 1.5.5) applications running in production.   I am in the process of upgrading to django-cms 3.1.1 (Django 1.8/python2.7).  I can get the test environment up and running with no issues.  However, importing my existing data has been the issue.  I have tried:

1. 'python manage.py dumpdata > dump.json' on the production server.
2. 'python manage.py loaddata -ignorenonexistent dump.json' on the development server.

The result is a series of tables already exist, violates null constrain, column does not exist, etc...

I then tried exporting directly from postgresql (as a backup) and restoring into the development install. The run python manage.py migrate.  Get a series of additional errors similiar to above.  The run migrate with the migrate --fake-initial and --fake.  Problem is that many of the pages (lets focus on cms_page as an example) has altered the fields in 3.x from 2.4. Migrate will only look at changes in the migration, the the difference in the table. Some fields were added, some were dropped.  I reviewed the cms_page migration 0001 file.  It creates the page table with extra columns.  Migration 0003 adds more fields and drops some.  The list goes on and on.

I have spent over three days trying to get my existing data migrated.  I even started with django-cms 3.0 put some plugins automatically upgraded my development environment to 3.1 (no, I did not include pip install --upgrade).  Just plain frustrating.

I even started to manually update the database tables.  Table constraints make this almost impossible.  Now I am looking at completely rewriting the django-cms migrations.  Is there something I am overlooking that will make data migration easier?  Maybe stay with django-cms 2.4 and upgrade django to a supported version?

Answer (score 3):

unless I have misunderstood what you are doing, I don't think you are doing this the right way.

You should not have trouble with migrations; they are designed specifically to make what you are doing (upgrading across database changes) easier.

If you find yourself manipulating database tables manually, you **are doing it wrong** and just making things horribly hard for yourself.

What should work:

1) Make a copy of the existing production 2.4.3 site - code, database and all. Don't touch a thing on the production site itself, if it works. From now on, work only on the copy.

2) Make sure that migrations really are up to date. It sounds from your description that perhaps they are not.

For each migration in the migrations directory, you should have an entry in the migrations table in the database. If not, but you are certain that your database is up-to-date with the model code, you can run `migrate --fake` to mark those migrations as run.

(You might find yourself in this position if you created your database with a `syncdb` and didn't run migrations with `--fake` to mark the tables as up-to-date, which is what I suspect may be the root of your problem.)

If you have some tables that are up-to-date and some that are not and inaccurate records of which ones are up-to-date in the migrations table, good luck; you're in a muddle that you will have to pick your way out of carefully.

3) Once your code, database tables and migration history are all singing from the same page and agree with each other, take another copy of the code and database and work from that, so you at least have a safe place to return to.

4) Now start upgrading the software, one component at a time as far as possible, and run ``migrate`. Use the [django CMS release notes](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/upgrade/index.html) to help you understand what is being changed, what else needs to be changed with it and any other steps you need to take.

Check after each component has been migrated that all is well.

5) You'll need to upgrade Django too; use the release notes to determine when you must upgrade Django before continuing with the next django CMS update.

Comment: Your step 2, above, may be the issue.  Over the last two days I have been working with Django-CMS 3.0.15, not 3.1.  I have gotten a little further, but still no luck.  I do work from a copy and a copy of the copy (both for django and the database, so I have a base to work from when I have to start again).  I will go back and start over following your guide.  I will post up as soon as I know more.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I will even take a an additional step back and try to get Django-CMS 2.4.3 to work with Django 1.7.  Running Python 2.7 already.

Comment: The database and south migrations were in sync.  Finally got a copy of Django-CMS 2.4/Django 1.5.5 running.  Rather than use postgresql restore database, I used the dumpdata/loaddata from django.  Few errors.  Had to TRUNCATE CASCADE 'django-content-types.  Django-form-designer was throwing an error during migration 0008.  Deleted a line (line #34) in them migration file: db.delete_column('form_designer_formlog', 'data') as discussed in https://github.com/samluescher/django-form-designer/issues/51.

Next to work on upgrading to django 1.6.

Comment: Using dumpdata/loaddata is an additional layer of pain. I'd definitely prefer to use a copy of the database first, just to eliminate further complicated steps that could go wrong.

Comment: Like loaddata, restoring a database via postgres throw errors too.  It has been over a week trying to get an update up and running.  Just too many changes between 2.4.3 and 3.0.  I have Django-cms 3.0.15 running on Django 1.7.10.  Load data gives the following error:
TypeError: Problem installing fixture '/ebs/djangocms30/localdealsmagazine/dumpOct21.json': get_db_prep_value() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connection'